# Firebase no me registra datos ayuda con kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin

Hola como ya se pudieron dar cuenta que soy nuevo en este tema de kotlin y estoy con mi app enredado ya que se registra el usuario pero los nombres y otros datos no se registran este es mi codigo.

> txtNames=findViewById(R.id.txtNames)
>           txtLastName=findViewById(R.id.txtLastName)
>           txtEmails =findViewById(R.id.txtEmails)
>           txtPass=findViewById(R.id.txtPass)

```
    progressBar= findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    dbReference=database.reference.child("User")

}

fun register(view: View) {
    CreateNewAccounts()
}

private fun CreateNewAccounts(){
    val names:String=txtNames.text.toString()
    val lastName:String=txtLastName.text.toString()
    val email:String=txtEmails.text.toString()
    val password:String=txtPass.text.toString()

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(names) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            progressBar.visibility= View.VISIBLE

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this){
                task->

                if(task.isComplete){
                    val user: FirebaseUser?=auth.currentUser
                    verifyEmail(user)

                    val userBD= user?.uid?.let { dbReference.child(it) }

                    userBD?.child("Name")?.setValue(names)
                    userBD?.child("lastName")?.setValue(lastName)
                    action()
                }
            }
    }

}
private fun action(){
    startActivity(Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java))
}
private fun verifyEmail(user:FirebaseUser?){
    user?.sendEmailVerification()
        ?.addOnCompleteListener(this){
            task->
            if(task.isComplete){
                Toast.makeText( this, "Email enviado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText( this, "Error al enviar el email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {

}

}
```

De antemanos Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene esta llamada `verifyEmail(user)` antes de seguir registrando los otros datos? ¿Depuraste los valores que intentas asignar al usuario?

Comment: Hola buena obsevacion es solo por confirmar. pero apesar que lo corregi continuo con el mismo problema me esta sacando canas verde jejeje

Comment: ¿Depuraste los valores, imprimiéndolos por ejemplo en el logcat? Quien sabe si no hay valores en `names, lastName ...`  Cuando algo no funciona debes mostrarlo para verificar lo que hay ahí.

Comment: Gracias amigo. Efectivamente no passaba nada la variables. Lo coregi remplazando la variable userDB.

Comment: tienes las reglas de Firebase Database en Publico para que cualquiera pueda subir datos? (Una configuración inicial para testear todo antes de ponerle reglas a la misma base de datos)